# Moving and Rotating an Image Texture

Tags: node-editor

I'm new to blender and 3D modelling. Until now I have just tried to teach myself the things I need by watching different tutorials or reading replies to questions with a similar problem to mine but right now I have a problem I'm not sure how to solve and I have looked around but since I am not even sure what my problem is I thought I ask for help.

I imported an Image as an Image Texture node and everything worked well but the image just appeared somewhere random and I can't get the UV map that I need to move the image to sync up with the UV map my output is using so I thought I try using a mapping note to change the position of the image directly but that only changed the colour value. Now I am not sure what would be the quickest solution for this problem.

What I currently have is this:
[image]

And this is what happens with a mapping node:
[image]

If anyone knows how to fix this problem or where I can find a good solution for this it would really help a lot.

Thank you for your advice

Answer (score 6):

You have your nodes wrong.

The `Mapping` node is indeed the one you need to rotate and move your texture but you should place it before your image and not after it :

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

The usage of the mapping node is self-explanatory, however, if you want to have full control over the texturing of your object, I suggest you to learn about UV unwrapping.

A good thing you want to remember is to **pay attention to the color of the node sockets** they are actually really important :

[image]
[image]

Purple is for Vectors, Yellow is for image or RGB(A) values, grey is for numbers (generally [0, 1]), green is for shaders. You should only connect two sockets of the same color unless you know exactly what you are doing.